# Isit possible to be notified when any resource starts or is terminated on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

How can I get a list of resources running on AWS? Its mainly to manage costs. I could do something like `aws ec2 describe-instances` for example, but its specific to EC2. Is there a general way to go about this so it captures *any* resource?

I think some may mention I can check the billing dashboard but thats a little too late (ok 1 month additional costs may be fine, but I'd like to be more proactive)

Comment: FYI, you can set up billing alerts in Cloudwatch. I have one for $100, $250, $500, $1000, etc. so I know how fast I'm burning through money and get an early warning if something is blowing up.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, both AWS Config and Cloudtrail could be useful in getting you start/stop alerts.